# MVC 5 decimal, after entry the value is changed

Tags: asp.net

here the value is like **29.0961** which I want exact this value in DB for that I have set on model :

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n4}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public decimal Amount { get; set; }
```

but in entry I get like ,   **29.0900** in View
and in in Database it's **29.09** which I want exact value which is entered by user.

thanks in advance

Comment: are you sure you're not looking to use a float or a double?

Comment: @peval27 I need value like , 0.1234 or 987.0009 do I need to user float?!

Comment: @peval27, any idia?!

Comment: How is your decimal field defined in the database, guessing it's a DECIMAL(8,4) for example which is 8 digits in total (four before decimal point and four after) if not it might be the database that is rounding the value?

Comment: @RoguePlanetoid it's  [Amount]       DECIMAL (18, 2) NOT NULL,

Comment: Change it to DECIMAL(18,4) instead, that should work - (18,2) version will only store two decimal places

Comment: @RoguePlanetoid yes, but I need in model so It could auto change on building project because there is many columns I need to change

Comment: Ok then you can maybe change "{0:n4}" to "{0:n2}" - although not 100% sure that's right so at least the two values are consistent - if that's what you need?

Comment: did, and 0:02 was same

Comment: @RoguePlanetoid , I change in database now when I enter value (29.1234) it's 29.1200 in database, which I need with out round off

Comment: It might be the issue with that formatting expression, but not sure how more to help, hopefully can get more advice as this question is quite new, hope have been of some help